# OpenGL Fragment Shader not working correctly - Unable to draw any color other than white

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

## Basic Description of Problem

I don't seem to be able to draw a triangle in any color other than white.

Here is my fragment shader code.

```
#version 330 core
out vec3 color;

void main()
{
    color = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

For the sake of clarity, I have not included any other code. My vertex shader works - I can see a white triangle on the screen.

I am new to the programmable pipeline way of using OpenGL.

## More Details and main.cpp Code

It has been suggested that the fault may be that my program falls back to the fixed pipeline way of doing things, so here is my main.cpp code which perhaps contains the problem rather than the shader code.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


GLuint LoadShaders(const char *vertex_shader_path, const char *fragment_shader_path)
{
    GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    std::ifstream vertex_shader_file;
    vertex_shader_file.open(vertex_shader_path, std::ios::in | std::ios::ate);
    if(vertex_shader_file.is_open())
    {
        unsigned long long vertex_shader_code_size = vertex_shader_file.tellg();
        char *vertex_shader_code = new char[vertex_shader_code_size];
        vertex_shader_file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        vertex_shader_file.read(vertex_shader_code, vertex_shader_code_size);
        vertex_shader_file.close();

        GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
        int InfoLogLength;

        std::cout << "Compiling Vertex Shader: " << vertex_shader_path << std::endl;
        glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, (const GLchar**)(&vertex_shader_code), (const GLint*)(&vertex_shader_code_size));
        glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

        glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
        glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
        char *VertexShaderErrorMessage = new char[InfoLogLength];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, nullptr, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        std::cout.write(VertexShaderErrorMessage, InfoLogLength);
        std::cout.flush();

        delete [] VertexShaderErrorMessage;
        delete [] vertex_shader_code;

        std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Could not open vertex shader source: " << vertex_shader_path << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    std::ifstream fragment_shader_file;
    fragment_shader_file.open(fragment_shader_path, std::ios::in | std::ios::ate);
    if(fragment_shader_file.is_open())
    {
        unsigned long long fragment_shader_code_size = fragment_shader_file.tellg();
        char *fragment_shader_code = new char[fragment_shader_code_size];
        fragment_shader_file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        fragment_shader_file.read(fragment_shader_code, fragment_shader_code_size);
        fragment_shader_file.close();

        GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
        int InfoLogLength;

        std::cout << "Compiling Fragment Shader: " << fragment_shader_path << std::endl;
        glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, (const GLchar**)(&fragment_shader_code), (const GLint*)(&fragment_shader_code_size));
        glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

        glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
        glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
        char *FragmentShaderErrorMessage = new char[InfoLogLength];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, nullptr, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        std::cout.write(FragmentShaderErrorMessage, InfoLogLength);
        std::cout.flush();

        delete [] FragmentShaderErrorMessage;
        delete [] fragment_shader_code;

        std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Could not open fragment shader source: " << fragment_shader_path << std::endl;
    }

}

GLuint vertexbuffer;

void display()
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, -10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    //glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLint)width, (GLint)height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0, (GLdouble)width/(GLdouble)height, 0.0, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if(key == 27)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char argv[])
{

    glutInit(&argc, &argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("window");

    glewExperimental = true;
    glewInit();

    GLuint vertexarrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexarrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexarrayID);

    static const GLfloat gvertexbufferdata[] = {-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(gvertexbufferdata), gvertexbufferdata, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);


    GLuint programID = LoadShaders("vertexshader.glsl", "fragmentshader.glsl");

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(programID);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

## Compilation Information

Here is some info on the compilation process if relevant:

I am compiling within codeblocks, and linking with `-lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lglut`. Optimization level is `-O3`. `--std=c++11`.

Comment: Output color has to be vec4, including alpha channel.

Comment: @Jaa-c Makes no difference I'm afraid

Comment: By the way, I am following this: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/

Comment: try to delete out vec3 color and assign gl_FragColor to vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) instead

Comment: @mlkn I get an error  that gl_FragColor is depreciated?

Comment: Someone close voted this as off topic? Is that a joke?

Comment: provide more code please

Comment: I didn't close vote, but I suspect it is because of missing code. Chances are that the problem is somewhere completely different. If it's drawing all white, one likely reason is that your shader program is not used at all, and you're falling back to the fixed pipeline.

Comment: @Jaa-c Fragment shader outputs don't have to be `vec4`. From the GLSL spec: "Fragment outputs can only be float, floating-point vectors, signed or unsigned integers or integer vectors, or arrays of any these."

Comment: @RetoKoradi Okay thanks for letting me know, I'll add more code!

Comment: You are never attaching the shader objects to the shader program. And you are never linking the shader program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacement `LoadShaders()` function, which was not complete.

```
GLuint LoadShaders(const char *vertex_shader_path, const char *fragment_shader_path)
{
    // Load and Compile Vertex Shader
    GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    std::ifstream vertex_shader_file;
    vertex_shader_file.open(vertex_shader_path, std::ios::in | std::ios::ate);
    if(vertex_shader_file.is_open())
    {
        unsigned long long vertex_shader_code_size = vertex_shader_file.tellg();
        char *vertex_shader_code = new char[vertex_shader_code_size];
        vertex_shader_file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        vertex_shader_file.read(vertex_shader_code, vertex_shader_code_size);
        vertex_shader_file.close();

        GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
        int InfoLogLength;

        std::cout << "Compiling Vertex Shader: " << vertex_shader_path << std::endl;
        glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, (const GLchar**)(&vertex_shader_code), (const GLint*)(&vertex_shader_code_size));
        glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

        glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
        glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
        char *VertexShaderErrorMessage = new char[InfoLogLength];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, nullptr, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        std::cout.write(VertexShaderErrorMessage, InfoLogLength);
        std::cout.flush();

        delete [] VertexShaderErrorMessage;
        delete [] vertex_shader_code;

        std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Could not open vertex shader source: " << vertex_shader_path << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Load and Compile Fragment Shader
    GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    std::ifstream fragment_shader_file;
    fragment_shader_file.open(fragment_shader_path, std::ios::in | std::ios::ate);
    if(fragment_shader_file.is_open())
    {
        unsigned long long fragment_shader_code_size = fragment_shader_file.tellg();
        char *fragment_shader_code = new char[fragment_shader_code_size];
        fragment_shader_file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        fragment_shader_file.read(fragment_shader_code, fragment_shader_code_size);
        fragment_shader_file.close();

        GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
        int InfoLogLength;

        std::cout << "Compiling Fragment Shader: " << fragment_shader_path << std::endl;
        glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, (const GLchar**)(&fragment_shader_code), (const GLint*)(&fragment_shader_code_size));
        glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

        glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
        glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
        char *FragmentShaderErrorMessage = new char[InfoLogLength];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, nullptr, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        std::cout.write(FragmentShaderErrorMessage, InfoLogLength);
        std::cout.flush();

        delete [] FragmentShaderErrorMessage;
        delete [] fragment_shader_code;

        std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Could not open fragment shader source: " << fragment_shader_path << std::endl;
    }

    // Link Shaders
    std::cout << "Linking Shaders" << std::endl;

    GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if(InfoLogLength == 0) InfoLogLength = 1;
    char *ProgramErrorMessage = new char[InfoLogLength];
    glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, nullptr, ProgramErrorMessage);
    std::cout.write(ProgramErrorMessage, InfoLogLength);

    glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

    return ProgramID;

}
```

Essentially the important changes are that the shaders were not linked before.

Comment: You should edit your question to include this missing code, not answer it

Comment: @rotoglup Why? Then there wouldn't be an answer to the question.

Comment: Not sure to follow you, what is the code you posted in the answer ? I understood it was the complete code that was part of the problem. Or is it the solution ?

Comment: @rotoglup This is a replacement function for the one given in the question, which does not work.

Comment: ok, but it would have been nice to mention the differences, and in which way it actually solved the problem. IMHO, just posting, long, raw code has no added value as an answer here, especially to yourself.

Comment: @rotoglup If you read the comments above you will see the explanation as to what was wrong.